# setRequestOrientation isn't working in Fragment (OS 8.0)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have some fragments A B C D are committed in MainViewActivity. C is a fragment allowed rotate (portrait or landscape), The orientation of fragment ABD is portrait.

This is config in manifest:
  **android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"**

And I called setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) method in **onCreate** of MainViewActivity.
In fragment C I called: getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_UNSPECIFIED) in onCreateView.

**My issue:**
    - When we are rotating the device to landscape and opening the application, fragment A is rotating to landscape and after 2 seconds it is rotating to portrait. It is just happening on OS 8.0 (Oreo). I don't know why.

Comment: Same issue faced by me.. it would be helpful if someone could post a reply